# sass convert px to vw

Tags: css, function, sass

I found a tutorial on how to write function that converts pixels to vw:

```
@function get-vw($target) { 
  $vw-context: (1000*.01) * 1px;
  @return ($target/$vw-context) * 1vw;
}
```

usage on tutorial:

```
.headline {
  font-size: get-vw(72px);
}
```

but when I use it like its explained nothing happens
my browser returns:

> <strike>font-size: get-vw(44px);</strike>  Invalid property value

Since I don't need learn sass at this moment but need only way to convert px to vw can someone help me to make this work?

Comment: are you using Sass to generate your styles?

Comment: I use Statamic framework and it's including sass since all is written inside of .scss files(sass folder) and gulp watch is running in background to generate my css

Comment: WOW found the solution, I have 1 file that is importing my file and my function was there but it was not included on my homepage so I guess I need to create separate file functions.scss and import it like other files...

Answer (score 5):

```
@function vw($px-vw, $base-vw: 1292px)    
  @return ($px-vw * 100vw) / $base-vw

.container
font-size: vw(16px)
```

Answer (score 3):

Did you test this?

```scss
@use "sass:math"; //You can use "sass:math"

$vw-viewport: 1920;
@function get-vw($font){
    $vw-context: $vw-viewport * 0.01 * 1px;
    @return math.div($font, $vw-context) * 1vw;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:
**1. Create a function**

```
$vw-viewport: 1920;
@function get-vw($font){
  $vw-context: $vw-viewport * 0.01 * 1px;
  @return $font / $vw-context * 1vw;
  @return $font;
}
```

**2. Apply the function**

```
.font20{
    font-size: get-vw(20px);
}
```

Comment: why did you used vw-viewport fixed value?

Comment: @SanskarTiwari It's just an example of the base value, you can set it to your needs

Answer (score 0):

The above didn't work for me but this did :

```
@function strip-unit($number) {
    @if type-of($number) == 'number' and not unitless($number) {
        @return $number / ($number * 0 + 1);
    }

    @return $number;
}

@function get-vw($px-vw, $base-vw: 1920px){
    @return #{strip-unit($px-vw) * 100 / strip-unit($base-vw)}vw;
}
```